# True/False: Differentiablity #2

Tags: real-analysis

If the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f(x)\le f(0)$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, then $f'(0)=0$.

---

I think this one is false.

By the definition of differentiable,

$f'(0)=\lim_{x_n \to 0}\dfrac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}$

but $f(x_n)-f(0)\le 0$ so $f'(0)\le 0$

Comment: The result is true. Your conclusion only works if you know that $x_n> 0$. By the way, what is the $n$ doing in your notation? Why are you looking at sequences?

Comment: $n$ is going to infinity. This is for a first course in real analysis, and my professor wants us to use sequences. And I thought I was looking at any $x_n$. Does it matter that I didn't specifically look at $x_n<0$?

Comment: Of course it matters: $\frac{3}{-2}$ is not positive, although $3>0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Well from the given conditions it is clear that $f$ attains a local maximum at $x = 0$ and since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ we have $f'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in part, but remember that $x_n$ could be positive OR negative.